# Data permission: what if adding only write permision to a file?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, permissions

What if a user got only write access to a file? Is he able to read the file or only to "write"? However, if you can write, you can also read, so this doesn't make sense?

The question is for Unix-like system also for windows system, I'm sure there is a difference right? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### Linux

You could append text to the file even if you can't read it. Check this example:

#### Create a file with one line

```
nine@nine-laptop:~$ echo "Some text" >/tmp/testfile.txt
```

#### Show that file

```
nine@nine-laptop:~$ cat /tmp/testfile.txt
Some text
```

#### Make it write only

```
nine@nine-laptop:~$ chmod 200 /tmp/testfile.txt
```

#### Show file with permissions

```
nine@nine-laptop:~$ ls -l /tmp/testfile.txt  
--w------- 1 nine nine 10 nov 14 10:54 /tmp/testfile.txt
```

#### Try to read it (which won't work)

```
nine@nine-laptop:~$ cat /tmp/testfile.txt  
cat: /tmp/testfile.txt: Access denied
```

#### Append text to end of file

```
nine@nine-laptop:~$ echo "Appended text" >>/tmp/testfile.txt
```

#### Set permissions to read and write

```
nine@nine-laptop:~$ chmod 600 /tmp/testfile.txt
```

#### Show the file (which now has one more line)

```
nine@nine-laptop:~$ cat /tmp/testfile.txt
Some text
Appended text
```

### BSD

Works precisely the same as on Linux.

### Windows

Adding weeks comment: It works the same in Windows. Exept there are several rights in write permission, like "Write data", "Append data", "Write Attributes", "Write Extended Attributes"..

Comment: Yes, it works the same in Windows. Exept there are several rights in write permission, like "Write data", "Append data", "Write Attributes", "Write Extended Attributes"..

Comment: Oh! That sounds nice :)

Comment: +1 for giving a good answer, complete with explanations.

Answer (score 1):

***nix:**

For *nix systems you can simply set "write-only" which works as expected. There is no matter why it should not. I don't understand your assumtion of automatically get read access... it's wrong. You can e.g. append to the file with no problem.

---

**Windows:**

It is possible to modify the permissions to only have "write"-access but my tests show that even it should work from what the properties show, it doesn't and always gives "Access denied". I think it is by design not meant to set only write on NTFS.